# Require JS error On megento 2.3.2 Upgrade

Tags: magento2.3.2

I have Upgraded my Magento 2 webshop from `2.2.5` into `2.3.2`.

After that PDP page gives console error saying below message.

> GET
>   https://mylocal.dev/static/xxxxxxx/frontend/Vendor_name/Theme/us_US/*.js
>   net::ERR_ABORTED 404
>
> Error: Script error for: *

Any answer for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

clean the cache : `php bin/magento c:c` and `php bin/magento c:f`

clean `var/view_preprocessed` **content** (content and not folder)

clean `pub/static` **content** (content and not folder)

deploy the static content = `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`